# Developing same UI using Constraints for 3.5 and 4 inch screens (only Portrait Mode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, constraints

1. What i need is to develop View and want it sub views (button, images, label) to get resize according to the size of screen.
2. Programatically and with the help "Struts and Springs", i am able to fulfil my requirement by unchecking the autolayout functionality and applying struts and springs with some codes for logo to get resize:

   if (iPhone4Or5oriPad==5)
       {
           self.imageLogo.frame = CGRectMake(TSImage_X_Co_ordinator, TSImage_Y_Co_ordinator, TSImage_WIDTH, TSImage_HEIGHT);
       }
3. I want this to be simple i.e by applying constraints let all subview get resize to get same look and feel for 3.5 and 4 inch screens.
4. When i use Autolayout this is what it appears for 4 inch screen which is upto my requirement:
   [image]
5. But The issue is with its appearance in 3.5 inch screens.
   [image]
6. Then i applied constraints to all the subviews.
   [image]
7. After applying constraints on 4 inch screen which is ok:
   [image]
8. After applying constraints on 3.5 inch screen (Image logo get press more than needed):
   [image]
9. Please note via coding and "Struts and Springs", i am able to develop same UI for 3.5 and   4 inch screens. I am eager to know: is their better way that i select all my subviews and apply some constraints and i get the same look and feel for 3.5 and 4 inch screens or is their any better way to do this?. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select the Image View and then under Attribute Inspector change Mode to Aspect Fill.

Comment: so the steps i should follow are: 1. Autolayout checked. 2. apply constraints as i have applied 3.and make image view Aspect File. Am i right? (Thank You for your response)

Comment: It is giving same look. Is this the standard way what i am following to get same Look and feel for 3.5 and 4 inch screens using constraints for only portrait mode? Thanks again.

Comment: just make sure to select the Image View (your logo) and switch to Aspect Fill (not Scale to Fill). also comment out the code you have at step 2 which resizes the logo. just try the Aspect Fill alone.

Comment: Yes, i did and its working. so This (Aspect Fill for UIImageView) + rest what i followed is the solution to make all my similar views compatible for 3.5 and 4 inch screens (Portrait Mode) and is the standard procedure, Correct?

Comment: it is the right procedure if you want to only affect the image (logo), yes.